# Curl (can't hide output)

Tags: php, curl

i maked this function:

```
function makeRequest($url,$browser,$ip,$cookie = false,$referrer = null)
{
if($referrer==null)
{
    $refferer = 'http://google.com';
}
$headers = array();    
$headers[] = "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: ".$ip;    
$headers[] = "X_FORWARDED_FOR: ".$ip;    
$headers[] = "REMOTE_ADDR:". $ip;    
$headers[] = "REFERRER: ".$referrer;    
$headers[] = $browser;
$ch = curl_init();   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); 
if($cookie!==false)
{
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);  
}    
else
{
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);  
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referrer);

if($cookie==false)
{
    $return = curl_exec($ch);
}
else
{
    $return = 'hidden content';
    curl_exec($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
 return $x;
}
```

But everytime returning the content, if i already set cookie to false.
I don't know how can i do that.

I tried with:

CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 
CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 
CURLOPT_HEADER

But nothing...

Thank's (sorry for my eng)

Comment: You need to put `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` always to `true` if you don't want to result to be outputted immediately (and not only if your `$cookie` is true)

Comment: It's works, anyway, the response it's a big content, is a way to just ping the adress?or set a limit to content received? It's important the method will be curl, because i need the cookie file. Thank's very much.

Comment: I maked with: CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  i hope that is right way.

Comment: If you want to act it like a `ping` you can do a `head` or an `options` request. : `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'HEAD');`